# flutter firebase analytics does not log every event

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've created an extended `NavigatorObserver` to listen to push and pop events from the app's navigator. Within this observer, I'll try to log screen view events to firebase analytics.

While I'm debugging in the DebugView of firebase's webtool, I get some `screen_view` events, but not all of them and it looks like, they are randomly popping up - or not popping up. I have no idea, if the problem lies in my code or in the debug view of firebase.

This is my `main.dart`

```js
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
      child: MainApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MainApp({super.key});

  /// Initialze AppRouter
  final AppRouter _appRouter = AppRouter();
  final NavigatorObserver _navObserver = AppNavigatorObserver();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      ...
      child: MaterialApp(
        locale: ...,
        supportedLocales: ...,
        localizationsDelegates: ...,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(...),
        title: 'DEMO APP',
        onGenerateRoute: _appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
        navigatorObservers: [_navObserver],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and that's the `AppNavigatorObserver` class

```js
class AppNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  static final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      log('POP to ${previousRoute.settings.name}');
      _logScreenView(previousRoute.settings);
    }
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    log('PUSH to ${route.settings.name}');
    _logScreenView(route.settings);
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
  }

  void _logScreenView(RouteSettings settings) async {
    switch (settings.name) {
      /// XY Page
      case XyPage.routeName:
        await _analytics.logScreenView(
            screenName: settings.name, screenClass: 'XY Page');
        break;

      /// Page with Arguments
      case ArgPage.routeName:
        final ArgPageArguments args =
            settings.arguments as ArgPageArguments;
        await _analytics.logScreenView(
            screenName: '${ArgPage.routeName}/${args.record.key}',
            screenClass: 'Testpoint ${args.record.key}');
        break;

      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The log sends my perfectly every pop and push with route name etc. on my debug console. but just a few of them do appear in the firebase's debug view.

** **UPDATE 30 Nov 23** **
A day later everything works fine. Every event pops up in the debug view. No idea what happened. It took me a whole day of searching for the bug. I assume, firebase analytics had a hiccup yesterday.